# C - Server/Client Tic-Tac-Toe Game - Read/Write index file?

Tags: c, semaphore, shared-memory

I have both a client and server programs that allow users to connect to a server and play tic-tac-toe. However, I ran into a wall as to how to implement a sort of user record storage system for the server.  What I mean by this is:

When a player connects to the server they are asked if they are a new player...if so then I want to create a new player record which consists of a username, first, and last name and record of wins/losses and ties (I know how to do this). That will be written to an index file. When an existing player connects to the server, they will enter only the username and the server will scan the index file for the player record and retrieve it. (Not really sure how to accomplish this)

When two consecutive players form a game, the opponent's record is displayed before the game starts. This is where I am having trouble... How do I scan the index file for an exisiting username and then retrieve its records.  I then want to display the opponents records to eachother before the game starts.

I have so much code it would be a pain to post for you to read through. I've heard maybe semaphores or shared memory might solve my questions?

Thanks

Yeah I figured that might be the case...I was wondering if it was possibly without doing so...like strictly using read/writes

Comment: What is your platform and threading library? (either way the answer should still be a database.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to use a database for this.  I'd recommend going with Sqlite.